# Vertical border/divider centered in header

Tags: html, css, header, nav

Is it possible, *and fairly easy*, to create a centered vertical border in my header? I want it to divide my logo/h1-text and my navbar.

I know the css is messy, i just learned html and css last week! I could probably remove some of the css.

```css
        header {
            height: 60px;
            width: 85%;
            /background-color: white;
            margin: 0 auto;
            /box-shadow: 0px 2px 31px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.86);
            /border: 2px solid #333;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            /border-sizing: border-box;
            /-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            /-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            z-index: 999999;
        }


        header #kage > *, header li {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        header li {
            padding: 0 8px 0 8px;
            float:left;
        }

        #kage {
            width: 99%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            height: 100%;
            line-height: 59px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .button1:hover {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }
        .button2:hover {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }
        .button3:hover {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }

        .active {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        header a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #333;
            position: relative;
        }

        header h1 {
            margin: 0;
            float: left;
            height: 100%;
            text-shadow: 1px 2px lightgrey;
        }

        header h1:hover {
            color: #f2f2f2;
        }

        #topnav {
            height: 100%;
            /*float: right;*/
            font-weight: 700;
            font-size: 1.3em;
            width: 310.95px;
        }

        header ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
        }
```

```html
    <header>
      <div id="kage">
      <a href="index.html"><h1>H1 TEXT HEREEEEE</h1></a>
        <nav id="topnav">
            <ul class="menu">
                <a href="index.html"><li class="button1 active">Home</li></a>
                <a href="profil.html"><li class="button2">About</li></a>
                <a href="mdu.html"><li class="button3">MDU</li></a>
            </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
```

Seems like you need to run the snippet in full screen, so the header wont break to two lines.

Comment: Set a border-right on the div that contains your logo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways doing this.
I think the simplest one is to put a border-left on your #topnav.

```
#topnav {
            height: 100%;
            /*float: right;*/
            font-weight: 700;
            font-size: 1.3em;
            width: 310.95px;
            border-left: 2px solid rgb(0,0,0);
            margin: 0 0 0 40px;
        }
```

I easily added a border with 2 pixels on the left side of you topnav, width the color black.
And adjusted it a bit with margin on the left side. margin: 0 0 0 40px; ~ (margin: top right bottom left)

```css
        header {
            height: 60px;
            width: 85%;
            /background-color: white;
            margin: 0 auto;
            /box-shadow: 0px 2px 31px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.86);
            /border: 2px solid #333;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            /border-sizing: border-box;
            /-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            /-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            z-index: 999999;
        }


        header #kage > *, header li {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        header li {
            padding: 0 8px 0 8px;
            float:left;
        }

        #kage {
            width: 99%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            height: 100%;
            line-height: 59px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .button1:hover {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }
        .button2:hover {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }
        .button3:hover {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }

        .active {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        header a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #333;
            position: relative;
        }

        header h1 {
            margin: 0;
            float: left;
            height: 100%;
            text-shadow: 1px 2px lightgrey;
        }

        header h1:hover {
            color: #f2f2f2;
        }

        #topnav {
            height: 100%;
            /*float: right;*/
            font-weight: 700;
            font-size: 1.3em;
            width: 310.95px;
            border-left: 2px solid rgb(0,0,0);
            margin: 0 0 0 40px;
        }

        header ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
        }
```

```html
    <header>
      <div id="kage">
      <a href="index.html"><h1>H1 TEXT HEREEEEE</h1></a>
        <nav id="topnav">
            <ul class="menu">
                <a href="index.html"><li class="button1 active">Home</li></a>
                <a href="profil.html"><li class="button2">About</li></a>
                <a href="mdu.html"><li class="button3">MDU</li></a>
            </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: Alright mate thank you. Though i found something i think would be smarter. Inbetween my H1 and topnav, i put an empty div with width: 4px and background-color: black.
That actually did the job aswell.

Comment: Although, as you said by yourself, you had to adjust the h1 margin-left på 40px to make it fit.
How come? my topnav seems to have an invisible margin.
margin-left: 0
left: 0
doesnt work?

Comment: ^^ You're welcome. I didn't adjust the margin-left from the h1, it makes no sense :) I adjusted the margin-left of the #topnav <nav> element

Comment: If you like to adjust the h1, you have to set margin-right. but remind, that the <h1> is inside an <a>

Comment: Ohh i see it now - i just misunderstood what you where saying.
I got my problem solved now - thanks alot mate!

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your HTML and CSS and still realize the layout that you are looking for.

Use the `header` element as your parent container for your logo and navigation links.

Within the `header`, have two child elements, `h1` and `nav`, and let both of these be inline-block elements.

If you want the child elements centered within `header`, use `text-align: center` to adjust the positioning.

The `header` may wrap on small screen sizes, and you could use `white-space: nowrap` to prevent that from happening (your design choice).

You can then adjust margin, padding and border values to control the spacing between the various links.

Note that for `nav`, apply `vertical-align: top` otherwise you get some extra whitespace above or below the baseline.

Also, if you specify `height` for the `header`, also specify `line-height` so that the inline child elements are vertically centered (if that is what you want).

```css
header {
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px dotted blue; /* for demo only */
  text-align: center; /* optional? */
  white-space: nowrap; /* to prevent line from wrapping, optional */
}
header h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 10px; /* adjust to taste */
  padding-right: 10px; /* add whitespace before vertical border */
  height: 100%;
}
header h1 a {
  text-shadow: 1px 2px lightgrey;
}
header h1:hover a {
  color: #f2f2f2;
}

header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.button:hover {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
.active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
nav {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-left: 10px; /* whitespace after vertical border */
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  border: 1px dotted gray; /* for demo only */
}
nav a {
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1><a href="index.html">H1 TEXT HEREEEEE</a></h1>
  <nav>
    <a href="index.html" class="button active">Home</a>
    <a href="profil.html" class="button">About</a>
    <a href="mdu.html" class="button">MDU</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Wow this actually helped me a lot!
Thanks for this. My css and html started to get so messy - and when you are knew and aint 100% sure about anything, i wouldnt just remove anything.
Thank you for your time!